# Elegant form of $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right)^d$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients

## Question

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers and $x \in (0,1)$, we can then consider the series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n.
$$
Let now $d\in \{2,3,\dots\}$ we can then consider $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right)^d$. I would like to write this in the following form:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right)^d = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n, \qquad (1)
$$
for certain $b_n$.

## Own Attempt

From the [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) we find that it can be written as:
$$
\sum_{\sum_n k_n = d} \binom{d}{k_1,\dots} \prod_{t=0}^\infty (a_t x^{t})^{k_t}
=
\sum_{\sum_n k_n = d} \binom{d}{k_1,\dots} \sum_{v=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\sum_t t k_t = v} \left(\prod_{t=0}^\infty (a_t)^{k_t} \right) x^{v}
$$
we can now try to move all these sums to the left, this way we can write:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right) = \sum_{v=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{\sum_n k_n = d} \binom{d}{k_1,\dots} \sum_{\sum_t t k_t =v} \left( \prod_{t=0}^\infty a_t^{k_t} \right) \right) x^v
$$
we have thus found the representation $(1)$ with:
$$
b_v = \sum_{\sum_n k_n = d} \binom{d}{k_1,\dots} \sum_{\sum_t t k_t=v} \left( \prod_{t=0}^\infty a_t^{k_t}\right).
$$
I was wondering if there isn't a more elegant representation of these $b_v$?

Comment: At first glance, this looks exactly right. I don’t know of anything better, but some experts may likely know more than I do.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work with this!

Comment: (1) Feng Qi, Chao-Ping Chen, and Dongkyu Lim, Several identities containing central binomial coefficients and derived from series expansions of powers of the arcsine function, Results in Nonlinear Analysis 4 (2021), no. 1, 57--64; available online at https://doi.org/10.53006/rna.867047. (2) Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions, AIMS Mathematics 6 (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about what you consider "elegant", but are you aware that [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) can be expressed in terms of [(partial) Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials)? (See also [Charalambides's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=PDMGA-v5G54C&pg=PA420).)

Applied to your problem, we have

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n x^n\right)^d=\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{d}\frac{d!}{(d-j)!}a_0^{d-j}B_{n,j}(a_1,2a_2,\dots,n!a_n)\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: I was not aware of this, this is a very nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for the general formula of the Cauchy product of $d$ equal power series.

Consider two power series, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$, repectively convergent in $A$ and $B$. Then its Cauchy product is defined as

$$ \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m x^m \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n \right) \doteq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\ell=0}^k a_{\ell}\ b_{k-\ell}\ x^k $$

and converges at least in $A \cap B$. Letting $c_k = \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^k a_{\ell}\ b_{k-\ell}$ we see that the R.H.S. is also a power series, namely

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k $$

Since you are interested in the case of the Cauchy product of $d$ equal power series we write

$$ \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \right)^d = \prod_{k=1}^d \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\right) $$

Now we just apply $d-1$ times the Cauchy product definition for two power series to obtain

$$ \sum_{n_1=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n_2=0}^{n_1} \cdots \sum_{n_d=0}^{n_{d-1}} a_{n_d}\ a_{n_{d-1} - n_d}\ \cdots a_{n_1 - n_2}\ x^n $$

Thus
$$ \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \right)^d = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n $$

with
$$ b_n = \sum_{n_2=0}^{n} \cdots \sum_{n_d=0}^{n_{d-1}} a_{n_d}\ a_{n_{d-1} - n_d}\ \cdots a_{n_1 - n_2} $$

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the product you will obtain a sum of products of the form $a_{n_1} a_{n_2} \cdots a_{n_d} x^{n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_d}$ which will be gathered if they share the same exponent of the $x$ variable. Hence
$$b_n = \sum_{n_1 + \cdots + n_d = n} a_{n_1} a_{n_2} \cdots a_{n_d},$$
where the sum is extended to all possible tuples $(n_1, \ldots, n_d)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying their sum is $n$.